# Magento: Get current active step in onepage checkout

Tags: magento

How can I get the active step in onepage checkout?

Thanks for help.

Comment: the `<li>` will have `active` class if that step is currently active. so may be you can check it?

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh Mehta; I have observed this in onepage.phtml, but I have not come to understand how it works exactly... I have to show custom steps design like an horizontal breadcrumbs in the top of the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active step section will have "active" class for it's LI tag.

It's done via the Accordion js class - method *openSection* (see js\varien\accordion.js). The Accordion itself is triggered by the Checkout js class - method *gotoSection* (file \skin\frontend\base\default\js\opcheckout.js).

Both Checkout and Accordion classes are instantiated in onepage.phtml template.

Comment: Thanks Oleg Kulik, have you an idea how can I get the active step with php ? I need it in a php variable.

Comment: Unfortunately Magento doesn't store Active Step parameter in php, that's why if you refresh onepage checkout page, it will go to the beginning, no matters where you were before that

Comment: And how can I write the current step (or stepId) in a js variable in the top of the file onepage.phtml ? Thanks a lot for any solution.

Comment: If what you want is update some text node with Active Block identifier as soon as it's opened by js, you need to add something like this to `Checkout.gotoSection` method: `$('yourBlockId').update(section)`

Comment: Where can I find the method `Checkout.gotoSection` ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's inside the opcheckout.js file - the base version path is `skin\frontend\base\default\js\opcheckout.js`

Comment: I am adding a custom step on top but its not open when the page is the load. I want to open my custom step open when the page is a load which is top of the step

Answer (score 2):

If you just wanted to add some code to your own JS file or inline in onepage.phtml, you can use this to hook into `gotoSection()`.

```
Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = Checkout.prototype.gotoSection.wrap(
    function(parentMethod, section, reloadProgressBlock) {
        // Call parent method
        parentMethod(section, reloadProgressBlock);
        console.log(section);
    }
);
```

Note: make sure you wrap this in an onload wrapper.